# Como determinar o nível do personagem pelo ganho de experiência?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Criei este calculo baseado em múltiplos abaixo para determinar quanto o personagem necessitará possuir de experiência para subir de nível.

```
float NeededExperience(int level, float experienceRatio = 100F)
{
    float neededExperience = ((level - 1) * experienceRatio) * level;

    if(neededExperience == 0F)
        neededExperience = experienceRatio;

    return neededExperience;
}
```

Com esta função, definindo que o `experienceRatio` é igual a 100, e o nível do usuário é 1, ele precisará de 200 de experiência para alcançar o nível 2 e 600 para o nível 3...

Mas gostaria de fazer o calculo contrário, que calcule o level do personagem a partir da quantidade de experiência que ele possui, por exemplo: um usuário que possui entre 2000 e 2999 de experiência está no nível 5.

Ou caso esta não seja a melhor forma de calcular experiência, também aceito sugestões.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O seu problema não é de programação, e sim de matemática.

O seu cálculo de experiência usa a seguinte "fórmula":

```
float neededExperience = ((level - 1) * experienceRatio) * level;
```

Chamando `neededExperience` de [image: e], `level` de [image: l] e `experienceRatio` de [image: r], isso é matematicamente equivalente a:

[image: equação matemática]

Logo, pode-se utilizar manipulações algébricas para isolar [image: l] em uma equação do segundo grau:

[image: isolando l]

Lembrando do seu ensino médio, você pode usar a [Fórmula de Báscara](http://www.infoescola.com/matematica/formula-de-bhaskara/) para obter as "soluções" (as raízes) de uma equação do segundo grau, usando os termos de cada "parte" da equação:

[image: termos]

Logo, o valor de [image: l] é calculado fazendo-se:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> No passo 4 é mantido apenas o sinal positivo porque o valor da raiz do
>   discriminante [image: raiz do discriminante] será quase sempre maior do
>   que [image: 1], de forma que a equação tem duas soluções: uma
>   positiva e uma negativa. Mas como não há nível negativo, não faz
>   sentido a solução negativa da equação.

Observe também que essa função matemática é contínua, de forma que ela retorna valores reais (quebrados, ou seja, um `float` ou `double` ao invés de um `int`). Como no seu caso a experiência limita os níveis por cima, na implementação você deve truncar o resultado para um inteiro (simplesmente ignorando as casas decimais).

Eu implementei essa equação no Excel para ilustrar as respostas obtidas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observe que a fórmula que está na célula C8 é exatamente a equação acima. Ela foi copiada para as demais células, e sempre referencia o `experienceRatio` fixo na célula D5.

No seu caso, para implementar em C#, basta fazer:

```
private static int CurrentLevelByExperience(float currentExperience, float experienceRatio = 100F){
    return Math.Truncate((1 + Math.sqrt(1 + 4*currentExperience/experienceRatio)) / 2);
}
```

Comment: Com este método eu conseguiria modificar para também ter o resultado no sentido oposto? passando como parâmetro o level e retornando a experiência necessária.

Comment: Mas vc já faz exatamente isso na sua função original. Não há o que "modificar".